# Hazelcast topic not always delivering messages to listeners on a healthy cluster

Tags: hazelcast

I have a 3-member Hazelcast setup (version 3.11).  Each member defines a topic that it uses to receive responses from the other members:

```
int myServerId = ...
MessageListener<Response> listener = ...
TopicConfig cfg = new TopicConfig( "response-" + myServerId );
cfg.addMessageListener( listener );
```

When one of the other members receives a request (over a separate reliable topic), it processes it and sends back a response:

```
UUID correlationId = ...
Response response = ...
ITopic<Response> responseTopic = hazelcastInstance.getTopic( "response-" + fromServerId );
responseTopic.publish( response );
LOG.debug( "Sent response fromServerId={}, toServerId={}, correlationId={}: {}", myServerId, requestingServerId, correlationId, response );
```

Back on the original node, I'm sending 3-5 messages in quick succession.  On the receiving node, I'm seeing those coming in, getting processed, and the responses published to the topic:

```
2018-10-31 13:42:45,326 DEBUG [REMOTE] (connection-2) Sent response fromServerId=2, toServerId=1, correlationId=159153cf-636d-4165-8b48-8ffcbcf33ffa: ...
```

But then on the original node, I'm only seeing some of the messages coming in.  Sometimes it's 1 of 5 that doesn't make it.  Other times they all make it in.

I tried defining all 3 topics (response-1, response-2, response-3) in the configuration and only defining a listener on one of the topics (corresponding to the serverId) with seemingly no difference.  I also tried adding the listener after starting up the HazelcastInstance with no improvement.

Then I did a combination of the two (define all topics but register a listener once the HazelcastInstance is started and available.  <s>No change either.</s>

The problem goes away when I take my original approach of defining a topic exactly once per member including a listener and change it so I define all topics on all members and only adding a listener per node after the HazelcastInstance is established.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Topic in Hazelcast doesn't guarantee message delivery. Instead, you can use `ReliableTopic` feature. Please see details here: https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#reliable-topic